# Twitter Bootstrap, fonts are very thin in Firefox (Image attached)

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, cross-browser

I'm currently experiencing a problem with the Twitter Bootstrap, now I say a problem but the fonts even look 'thin' on the Bootstrap homepage too (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/).

See this image below to see the difference in font styles between FF and Chrome:

[image: See this image to see the difference in font styles between FF and Chrome]

In my opinion, the top menu bar is quite difficult to read and additionally the welcome text (h2) is not anywhere near as bold as in Chrome.

I've looked into text rendering tweaks such as anti-alias etc but to no avail.

Is there anything else I can try to remedy this?

Comment: Win 7 Home Premium 64-bit. Latest versions of both FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use a google font. Twitter bootstrap is great but I wouldn't use it for typography. You can import a google font into your website in a minute. I recommend open sans.